# Merge several Word files, using filename as Heading1, and demoted (embedded) heading

Tags: vba, merge, ms-word, document

I have a few hundred Word docx files, which I'd like to merge into a single docx file.

Each of these files has headings that are formatted using built-in Heading1, Heading2,.. styles, all of which are likely the same across the files, in terms of style formatting.

I'd like each file's content to be included in a Heading1 heading, named for the file's name. The document's headings should be demoted -1 inside of that, such that the document's own Heading1's become Heading2's, etc.

This task is complex enough that no GUI solution probably exists (Insert|Text|Object|TextFromFile only does a simple merge), and might be too complex for VBA also. .

Finally, a compromise solution might be using all these docs as subdocuments in a master document (as explained [here](https://officemastery.com/master-document-multiple-subdocuments-word/#t-1592879544654)), however I found this cumbersome. ACtualy merging them, as per the above, would be preferrable.

Comment: Just to be clear, "headers" are what appear at the top of the page above the top margin. Text in the main body of the document formatted with a heading style is a "heading". Do you want a solution for headers, or headings?

Comment: Simply using Insert|File as a brute-force approach is problematic. For some code that does most of what you want, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html. Getting the first heading 1 from each of the source files and adding that to the page header is a trivial addition - there's plenty of code around for that sort of thing.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt sorry about that, I did mean heading, not header - will edit

Comment: If you simply need *all* Heading 1s in the page header, a simple STYLEREF field in the header referencing the 'Heading 1' Style will do that.

Comment: I need the file's name to go as the Heading1 under which the file's contents is to be pasted. Sorry for the confusion : had written header in the initial question, but Ive now edited that.

Comment: Did you see my code to "downsize" the heading-paragraphs (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264608/16578424): you can create a heading1-paragraph in your target doc, run thhis macro on the source file and then copy the content of source file below the heading 1 in target doc

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to "downsize" the headings-styles

```vb
Public Sub downsizeHeadingHierarchy(doc As Word.Document)


'reset find object
With doc.Range.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With


Dim styleEnumFind As Long

'wdStyleHeading1 = -2, wdStyleHeading2 = -3 etc
For styleEnumFind = wdStyleHeading8 To wdStyleHeading1
    With doc.Range.Find
        .Style = ThisDocument.Styles(styleEnumFind)
        'e.g. styleEnumFind = -2 --> replace = -2 - 1 = -3
        .Replacement.Style = ThisDocument.Styles(styleEnumFind - 1) 'replace with next hierarchy
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Ike. Will this work on multiple docs though, pasting the content of each under the respective Heading1?

Comment: No - this part is "only" for downsizing the heading hierarchy for a given document. It shouldn't be to hard to find code examples copying several word docs into one.

Comment: It isn't indeed, but I'm still not sure who does the renaming of the Heading1 based on the file's name?

Comment: This code part only moves heading1 to heading2 etc. What you have to do: write the filename to your target document, apply heading1, add a new para, then open sourcedocument, run the above code on that doc, copy the content to your targetdocument below the filename, close sourcedoc without saving.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are referring to with the heading thing, but this code will copy everything from multiple word files in a folder, and paste it into a single word file. Once everything is consolidated in a single file, you can do whatever you want with it, like formatting headers.

```
Sub Foo() 
Dim i As Long 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Documents.Add 
With Application.FileSearch 
  'Search in foldername 
  .LookIn = "C:\test" 
  .SearchSubFolders = False 
  .FileName = "*.doc" 
  .Execute 
    For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count 
       If InStr(.FoundFiles(i), "~") = 0 Then 
         Selection.InsertFile FileName:=(.FoundFiles(i)), _ 
         ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False 
         Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak 
       End If 
     Next i 
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! as I mentioned, simplymerging several docs into one is simple enough with the builtin Word command. It's the naming of each Heading1 heading in the merged doc after each file's name, that is the problem. Doesn't look this script does that?